# About roots of polynomials

Tags: polynomials, limits-and-convergence

Let $n\in\mathbb N^*$, $P(x)=a_0+\dotsb+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+x^n$ and $r_1,\dotsc,r_n\in\mathbb C$ the roots of $P$.

> Is it true $\lim\limits_{\max(\lvert a_i\rvert,i=0\dotsc n-1)\rightarrow 0} \max(\lvert r_i\rvert,i=1\dotsc n)=0$?
>
> If there is an inequality between the two maxes, can you give it?

Comment: Yes. This follows from Rouché’s theorem.

Comment: Isn't there a standard inequality between the two maxes

Comment: @markvs can you give it ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [an application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometrical_properties_of_polynomial_roots#From_Rouch%C3%A9_theorem) of Rouché's theorem to polynomials. As I remember, it is used in one of the proofs of The Fundamental Theorem of Algebra.

Answer (score 4):

This has nothing to do with complex numbers, or Rouche's theorem. In any normed field, denote $r=\max|r_j|$ and $A=\max|a_j|$. Then
$$r^n\leq An\max\{1,r^{n-1}\}.$$
So if $r\leq 1$ then $r\leq (An)^{1/n}$ and if $r>1$, then
$r\leq An$.